# value of Integral on the contour

Tags: complex-analysis

I am self-studying complex analysis (Stein and Shakarchi) and I have a question, on the integral over a contour. The problem is to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} dx$. He setups a contour as follows:
[image: page1]
[image: page2]

My question has to do with this evaluation of the contour of the top of the rectangle from right to left. He says the following:
[image: page3]
[image: page4]

I don't think I understand how he arrived at $-e^{2\pi i a}I_{R}$.

Comment: Think about what happens when you plug $z=x+i 2 \pi$ into the expression for $f(z)$.

Comment: Thanks @RonGordon. That answered it.

Comment: The integral is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}\, dx,$ no?

Comment: The book is Stein and Shakarchi, yes?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{\text{Top side}} = \int_{R}^{-R} \frac{e^{ax}e^{2\pi i a }\,dx}{1+e^{x}e^{2\pi i}}=-e^{2\pi ia }\int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{ax}dx}{1+e^x}=-e^{2\pi a i}I_R. $$